# How to do OR gate and AND gate operation implementation by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem to make JavaScript codes and HTML codes for implement the logic operation for OR-gate and AND-gate.First thing is, I need to make OR-gate object and AND-gate object with its operation("*", "+"). Full code is shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
/*var OR_gate = {
    name: "or_gate";
    operation: '+';

};
var AND_gate = {
    name: "and_gate";
    operation: '*';

};*/

function getOutputResult()
{
    var input1 = document.getElementByName('input1').value;
    var input2 = document.getElementByName('input2').value;
    if(document.getElementByName('gate').name == "or_gate")
    {
        var logic = input1 + input2;
    }
    if(document.getElementByName('gate').name == "and_gate")
    {
        var logic = input1 * input2;
    }
    document.getElementByName("output").innerHTML = logic;
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<h3><u> OR , AND gates operation </u></h3>
<form>

 Input 1: <select name="input1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">0</option></select><br><br>

 Input 2: <select name="input2"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">0</option></select><br><br>

 Operation gate: <select name="gate"><option name="or_gate" >OR gate</option><option name="and_gate" >AND gate</option></select><br><br>

 <button onclick="getOutputResult()">DONE</button>
 </form>
 <br><br>
 Result : <label name="output">OUTPUT</label>

 </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: "is not working"? So tell us what's going wrong.

Comment: JavaScript code not give output result. I couldn't find the way to debug this code.

Comment: I have changed my problem

Answer (score 1):

```
string logic = input1+operation+input2;
document.getElementByName("output").innerHTML = logic.value;
```

In JavaScript, you don't declare the type of a string explicitly.  Also, a string is primitive.  The default result for accessing the `value` property of a string is `undefined`.

There may be other things wrong as well, but you definitely need to change the above code to look like:

```
var logic = input1 + operation + input2;
document.getElementByName("output").innerHTML = logic;
```

Also,

```
getOutputResult(this(input1),this(input2),this(gate))
```

is not valid for anything.  It looks like you want to pass the `input1` and `input2` but you can't access them like `this(varname)`.  You need to grab it from the DOM.  The easiest way would probably just be to give each field a unique ID so that you can globally do something like `document.getElementById('input1_id').value`

Comment: I have edited that function getOutputResult(input1,input2,gate). Replaced string with var. is it correct or wrong?

Comment: @pushpikaliyanaarachchi - see my edit - the onclick attribute is still wrong